# adding bootstrap collapse to table cell with rowspan

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a table using html, bootstrap and js.
I have used rowspan to get cells of different height.

The third cell in each row has more rows than the rest of the cells(hence the rowspan) (If this line is not clear please take a look at the jsfiddle)

Now each of the row in the third cell is a collapsible. So when I click on row it should open another table. (I have just made the first row collapsible for simplicity)

I have 2 issues:

1) The width of the cell increases when I click the collapsible element and decreases when I hide the collapsible element. I want the width to remain the same.

2) I want to make the hidden table start from the same place as the outer tables. It  currently starts somewhere randomly on the page

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var list1 = {
    "Feature": "TestSuite",
    "Scenario": "TestName",
    "Step": "line1<br>line2<br>line3<br>line4<br>",
    "Result": "PASS"
  }

  var list2 = {
    "Feature": "TestSuite1",
    "Scenario": "TestName1",
    "Step": "line1.1<br>line2.1<br>line3.1<br>line4.1<br>",
    "Result": "PASS"
  }

  var dashboardMap = {
    "TestSuite1": [list1, list2],
  }
  for (var key in dashboardMap) {
    var resultsTable = dashboardMap[key];
    for (var i in resultsTable) {
      table = document.getElementById("resultsTable");
      row = table.insertRow(-1);
      cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
      cell1.innerHTML = "N/A";
      cell2.innerHTML = resultsTable[i].Scenario;
      var list = resultsTable[i].Step.split("<br>");
      var rowspan = 0;
      list.splice(-1, 1);
      for (var step in list) {
        rowspan++;
      }

      cell1.rowSpan = rowspan;
      cell2.rowSpan = rowspan;
      cell4.rowSpan = rowspan;

      var hiddenTable = '<table>      <tr>        <th>Company</th>        <th>Contact</th>        <th>Country</th>      </tr>      <tr>        <td>Alfreds</td>        <td>Maria</td>        <td>Germany</td>      </tr>      <tr>'

      cell3.innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button><i id="demo" class="collapse"> ' + hiddenTable + ' </i>'
      cell4.innerHTML = resultsTable[i].Result;
      var k;
      for (k = 1; k < list.length; k++) {
        row = table.insertRow(-1);
        cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = list[k];
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="temp" class="container">  
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="resultsTable">
      <thead>
        <tr class="highlight-header" rowspan="3">
          <th>header 1</th>
          <th>header 2</th>
          <th>header 3</th>
          <th>header 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been playing around with your fiddle a little. Quick question - did you intend to pull all the rows of the main table in the table header?

Comment: I don't understand point 2) where do you want the expandable table to start from?

Comment: @JVLobo  I want the header of the inner table (Company) to start where header 1 starts from.

Comment: @JSager Not sure I understand your question. Can you please explain?

Comment: Could you post an example of your desired result? (a screenshot for example)